# Can i view the raw request made by soap wcf call

Tags: asp.net-3.5, wcf-security

I am making a SOAP request using WCF to a third party service.  The service requires that I sign the request, which I think I am doing but I get the error: `Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel`  So I am wondering if there is a way to see the raw xml that is being sent so I can see where the problem is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can see the contents of a message by enabling [message tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) and using the Service Trace Viewer to [view the message logs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730918.aspx).

Having said that, the message `Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel` implies a problem at the transport level, so I doubt that you are going to find much of use in the message trace.  It likely means you don't have the right client certificate or none at all; [this thread](http://forums.asp.net/p/1106057/1695893.aspx#1695893) on the ASP.NET forums might help you out with that.

Answer (score 6):

```
OperationContext.Current.RequestContext.RequestMessage.ToString()
```