# How to intercept raw soap request/response (data) from WCF client

Tags: asp.net, wcf, soap

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292868/can-i-view-the-raw-request-made-by-soap-wcf-call) seems to be pretty close to what I am looking for - I was able to setup tracing and I am looking at the log entries for my calls to the service.

However I need to see the raw soap request with the data I am sending to the service and I see no way of doing that from the SvcTraceViewer (only log entries are shown but no data sent to the service) - am I just missing configuration?

Here's what I got in my web.config:

```
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel"
              switchValue="Verbose"
              propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="sdt"
              type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
              initializeData="App_Data/Logs/WCFTrace.svclog"  />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

Any help appreciated!

**UPDATE**: this is all I see in my trace:

```
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
  <System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
    <EventID>262163</EventID>
    <Type>3</Type>
    <SubType Name="Information">0</SubType>
    <Level>8</Level>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2010-05-10T13:10:46.6713553Z" />
    <Source Name="System.ServiceModel" />
    <Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-1501-0080000000f6}" />
    <Execution ProcessName="w3wp" ProcessID="3492" ThreadID="23" />
    <Channel />
    <Computer>MY_COMPUTER_NAME</Computer>
  </System>
<ApplicationData>
  <TraceData>
    <DataItem>
      <TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Information">
        <TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageSent.aspx</TraceIdentifier>
          <Description>Sent a message over a channel.</Description>
            <AppDomain>MY_DOMAIN</AppDomain>
            <Source>System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput+WebRequestHttpOutput/50416815</Source>
            <ExtendedData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2006/08/ServiceModel/MessageTraceRecord">
            <MessageProperties>
              <Encoder>text/xml; charset=utf-8</Encoder>
              <AllowOutputBatching>False</AllowOutputBatching>
              <Via>http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:9080/MyWebService/myService</Via>
            </MessageProperties>
          <MessageHeaders></MessageHeaders>
        </ExtendedData>
      </TraceRecord>
    </DataItem>
  </TraceData>
</ApplicationData>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't have a specific tab that shows just the SOAP message - but the XML tab does include the whole SOAP message - no??

[image]

What is missing for you from this snippet of XML here??

**UPDATE:** John, you're unfortunately not showing what your `<system.serviceModel>/<diagnostics>` section looks like - mine used for this result looks like this:

```
<diagnostics>
  <messageLogging 
      logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" 
      logMessagesAtServiceLevel="false"
      logMalformedMessages="true" 
      logEntireMessage="true"
      maxSizeOfMessageToLog="65535000" 
      maxMessagesToLog="500" />
</diagnostics>
```

Do you have the same settings? Maybe you're missing `logEntireMessage` or something else??

Comment: tnx for helping - updated question to show what I see in the xml. There's no Envelope! Am I missing something from config?

Comment: Also I seem to have a different version of svctraceviewer - the message tab next to the xml tab is not showing up

Comment: @JohnIdol: which binding are you using??

Comment: I was entirelty missing the messageLogging section! - do I need also need to use System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging or will the envelope show up even if I keep System.ServiceModel?

Comment: @JOhnIdol: you need both the <system.serviceModel>/<diagnostics>.... stuff I posted (sets up what gets logged), as well as your stuff in <system.diagnostics> (defined *where* that stuff gets logged to)

Comment: cool - but it doesn't seem to work with source --> name="System.ServiceModel" while it works with source --> name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging"

Comment: the log doesn't seem to refresh nicely - I have to wait minutes before I can see the entries and getting loads of errors when opening. Is there some process I need to kill to get it to persist or some other tip you can share? :)

Comment: @JohnIdol: not sure - I believe there are a couple of options you could set on the XmlWriterTraceListener to influence how and how quickly the file gets written / flushed to. Check out the MSDN docs for it! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.xmlwritertracelistener.aspx

Comment: this one did the trick --> <trace autoflush="true" /> :) - I am all set now thanks!

Comment: @JohnIdol: great to hear ! I was just gonna recommend that one :-)

Comment: Hey Marc - should I be able to see HttpHeaders as well from this log? I am having a problem where a service call is very slow through an HttpHandler and the only thing left to check are Http Headers --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876955/service-call-very-slow-if-going-through-httphandler/2877038#2877038 - you might answer to the new question if you know! :)

Answer (score 12):

I recently encountered the same problem as in the update to the original question: the trace was showing that a message had been sent, but the message itself wasn't there. For me, the fix was to add a System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging source. Here's my system.diagnostics config section:

```
<system.diagnostics>
   <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" 
              switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing" 
              propagateActivity="true" >
         <listeners>
            <add name="xml"/>
         </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
         <listeners>
            <add name="xml"/>
         </listeners>
      </source>
   </sources>
   <sharedListeners>
      <add name="xml" 
           type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" 
           initializeData="C:\logfiles\Traces.svclog" />
   </sharedListeners>
</system.diagnostics>
```

And my system.serviceModel / diagnostics section:

```
<diagnostics>
   <messageLogging
      logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true"
      logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true"
      logMalformedMessages="true"
      logEntireMessage="true"
      maxSizeOfMessageToLog="65535000"
      maxMessagesToLog="500" />
</diagnostics>
```

Once I added the MessageLogging source, the TraceViewer showed "Message Log Trace" traces which contained the actual SOAP messages.

Answer (score 0):

There is an another way to see XML SOAP - [**custom MessageEncoder**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.channels.messageencoder). The main difference from IDispatchMessageInspector / IClientMessageInspector is that it works on lower level, so it captures original byte content including any malformed xml.

In order to implement tracing using this approach you need to wrap a standard [textMessageEncoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/wcf/textmessageencoding) with [custom message encoder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.channels.messageencoder) as new [binding element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.textmessageencodingbindingelement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and apply that custom binding to endpoint in your [config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/custom-binding-transport-and-encoding).

Also you can see as example how I did it in my project -
[wrapping](https://github.com/capslocky/WcfSoapLogger/blob/master/src/Library/WcfSoapLogger/EncodingExtension/LoggingBindingElement.cs) textMessageEncoding, logging [encoder](https://github.com/capslocky/WcfSoapLogger/blob/master/src/Library/WcfSoapLogger/EncodingExtension/LoggingEncoder.cs), custom binding [element](https://github.com/capslocky/WcfSoapLogger/blob/master/src/Library/WcfSoapLogger/EncodingExtension/LoggingExtensionElement.cs) and [config](https://github.com/capslocky/WcfSoapLogger/blob/master/src/UsageExamples/ExampleBeta/Client/App.config).